# Getting Django to run script with parameters?

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble getting Django to run a Tweepy script with parameters. I seem to be able to get the script to run print statements when I start the server and create an instance, but I'm having a hard time getting it to take in a tag from the HTML input.

HTML Button:

```
<div class="col s12">
      <div class="input-field inline">
      <label for="User">Enter a term</label>
        <form action = "submit/" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
       <input id="Country" type="text" name="Country" maxlength="100" required value="{{ tag }}" />
       <button class="btn waves-effect red" type="submit" name="action">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
       </form>
      </div>
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import GetTweets
from . import live

# Create your views here.

#Index by Kenny P
def index(request):
    context = {'tag': ''}
    return render(request, 'visualize/index.html', context)

#Tweets by Kenny P. Tweet will return the tweets
def Tweets(request):
    #Terms we want displayed go here!
    print 'IN!!!'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        info = GetTweets(request.POST)

        if info.is_valid():
            country = request.POST['Country']
            tw = live.GetTweets(render_data.cleaned_data['Country'])

        else:
            country =  GetTweets()

    context = {
        'Country': country,
    }

    return render(request, 'visualize/index.html', context)

def submit(request):
    return render(request, 'visualize/index.html')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

#Search for the tag
class GetTweets(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField(label='User', max_length=30)
```

and finally, the (temporary) tweepy script:

```
import tweepy
import time
from collections import defaultdict
import json

consumer_key = "??"
consumer_secret = "??"
access_key = "??"
access_secret = "??"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


def GetTweets(tag):
  placeholder = []
  for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=tag).items(20):
    placeholder.append(tweet.created_at)
    placeholder.append(tweet.text)
  #created_at
  print '   placeholder 0 \n'
  print placeholder[0] 
  print placeholder[1]
  print ' placeholder 1\n'
  print placeholder[2]
  print placeholder[3]
```

URLS

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^submit', views.Tweets),
]
```

Comment: where's your urls.py?

Comment: @thebjorn I added them to the post. I didn't think it had to do with those.

Comment: the `Tweets` view isn't hooked up to an url (in urls.py) which means there is no way you can execute it from a button click. The url in your html-form's `action` attribute must match an url defined in urls.py to map to `views.py:Tweet`

Comment: Thank you @thebjorn , I've added the update URLS to this post. However, it doesn't seem to be running any tags entered from the html form yet.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass `tag` to your template, otherwise `{{ tag }}` will be empty. Change your `index()` view (iirc, in older versions of Django you would need to wrap the context dict in `template.Context(context)`:

```
context = {'tag': 'hello world']
return render(request, 'visualize/index.html', context)
```

Change your html to post to the correct url, e.g.:

```
<form action="submit/" method="post">
```

make sure the urls.py matches (you were missing `/$` at the end):

```
url(r'^submit/$', views.Tweets),
```

your urls.py also needs to match the view definition. If you define the view as taking a `tag` parameter:

```
def Tweets(request, tag):
```

then the urls.py needs to capture a field named `tag`, eg.:

```
url(r'^submit/(?P<tag>\w+)/$', views.Tweets),
```

but since you're passing the `Country` variable as a `POST` variable your url should be

```
url(r'^submit/$', views.Tweets),
```

and your view should be defined without a tag parameter

```
def Tweets(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        country = request.POST['Country']  # from the name= in the html input element
        # call twitter
        # redirect to a response page
    # setup form
    # render GET version of page..
```

Comment: Perhaps the context is not required for the index? It seems to just be putting the hello world text into my input box. Changing the HTML form action to submit/ just changes my URL after clicking submit (and continues to do so as you click it), I've tried redirecting it back to the index but I couldn't get it. I'm not sure if that url is necessary? I will update my code once again in the main post. Also, my live.py does not seem to run still as I don't get the print message in console.

Comment: I'm not understanding what your problem is.  If your `live.GetTweets` isn't called it must be because `if info.is_valid():` isn't true -- perhaps because the html doesn't have a user-field (which is the only field in the form pointed to by `info`..?)